# Is it possible to receive a traffic fine from Spain with a 50% discount?

Tags: spain, car-rentals, balearic-islands

After some holidays in Baleares Islands (SP) this Spring, I received a letter from some agency informing me of a (small, < 100€) traffic fine.

There is a photo of the rental car and the date indicated corresponds to when I was using it.

But there is just a photo of the car on a small road, no "speed limit" doesn't seem to be any red light or stop sign that I would have crossed, description is "Improper, careless or reckless driving" (which seems a bit surprising).

The letter indicates that if I pay it in timely manner (until the 27-December), I'll get a 50% discount.

Sender is

> Agència Tributària Illes Balears
>
> Cecilio Metelo 11A
>
> 07003 Palma
>
> Illes Balears, Spain
>
> bank account ES58 2100 0011 8702 0160 7668

To me this screams some scam attempt, I've never heard of getting a discount on tickets.

On the other hand, I of course want to avoid any issue when I return to Spain, if this is a legit fine.

Is that a thing in Spain (or at least in Baleares Islands)?

How can I check if that fine is legit?

Comment: You do actually get a 50% discount on traffic fines in Spain if you accept the fine and pay without contesting it and bringing the case to court. Such an arrangment is not very uncommon, in other countries you might initially be offered an already 'discounted' fine if accepting it and risk additional procedural costs if you bring the case to court. The address is also legit, but the letter may of course still be a scam. Do they offer contact by e-mail or phone?

Comment: It’s indeed quite common in several countries to get a discount if you pay within a very short time or to get a penalty if you take longer to pay. Whether that is a legitimate fine is another matter, but for the rental company to have handed out your details I would suppose they know it’s legitimate.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure I can name a single country that does not have a sliding scale for traffic tickets depending on how fast you pay them. The only thing that differs is whether that's presented as a “discount” on a nominal fine, an increased penalty if you don't pay in time, or a combination of both, but that's a technicality. So like the other commenters, I do not find that surprising at all.

Comment: In France (don't know of Spain), we have *vitesse excessive* (excessive speed) which is when the officer doesn't have a radar gun reading and feels you are going too fast for the circumstances (overtaking, coming into a sharp turn...)... This sounds very much like the same

Comment: The sender's name translates as "Balearic Islands Tax Agency". Do they issue fines for "Improper, careless or reckless driving"? Are there any contact details? There should be some way of contacting them if you intend to contest the fine.

Comment: i get exactly the same order for paying! Tried to call the "agencia tributaria illes balears", but nobody reacts.

Comment: No phone or email address, they only indicate that we can ask for more information and contact them by the postal address.

Comment: Clarifying the last comment: "Within this specified time you may also make submissions or propose and provide any evidence you might deem advisable. Submissions are to be sent in written form in Spanish language to: [postal adddress]".